# Share question to Social Media option or button is much needed

Tags: support, ios-app

First of all kudos to app development team for developing very clean and smooth App. I Liked the app.

I have noticed there is still no button or option to share a question on social media. That integration would be nice.

Update 1:

There is a share button when you click on 3 dots on right. I would suggest using UIActivitiViewController at first only when clicked on that 3 dots button. Would be intuitive I suppose.

[image]

Comment: I removed your note about the crash from this post to keep it focused on the sharing request. Feel free to make a new post tagged [tag:bug] if you can provide more information about that crash

Answer (score 12):

The advice below the line applies to the previous version. After the latest update to the app last night there is now a Share button at the bottom of every question and answer.

---

The functionality is already there but it is a bit cryptic.

Choose the three vertical dots to the right of where the user signs a question or answer and there is a Share option.

Answer (score 4):

As the app currently works, we cannot make the "three dots" button go directly to the sharing sheet, since there are many other options presented there (such as open in Safari/Chrome, Favorite, Flag, etc).

Regarding your crashes, please file another issue in meta with more details. I have found the crash report, but am having trouble reproducing.

Comment: I will try to provide details for sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is a little hidden at the moment, but you can do it by tapping on the three vertical dots visible in the right side of your screenshot, after which you'll see a menu featuring "Share".