# Last activity date isn't updated when question is destination of merge

Tags: bug, merged-questions, last-activity

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234661/share-question-to-social-media-option-or-button-is-much-needed) just became a destination of merge. Clicking on the last activity date correctly goes to the answer which got moved to this question because of merge. But it is still written that last activity date was 5 months ago.

> [image]

Comment: This isn't about migration, but rather merging. Those are two different things. (regarding the tags)

Comment: @Sha yeah, I know that migration and merging are different, just messed with tags :) thx

Comment: @Sha Thanks, great pic :)

Comment: Cheers, had to use a browser extension, but was worth it. (usually I stay away from extensions :))